# Is there an rest api or ansible module to register an VM in vCenter

Tags: ansible, vsphere, powercli, vcenter

I know we can do this in PowerCli, but would like to know if there is any other method to register an VM in vcenter like using vcenter api or ansible ?

For migrating a machine vCenter A to vCenter B, my vRO does not have access to the vcenterB, but I need to register the machine in vCenter B. It would be easy if I can use rest api or ansible module to do it or is there a way I can use VMWare converter with vRO ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here recently a module was added to Ansible that can do just that. The module: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/vmware/vmware_guest_register_operation.py

Some example code:

```
- name: Register VM to inventory
  vmware_guest_register_operation:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    validate_certs: no
    datacenter: "{{ datacenter }}"
    folder: "/vm"
    esxi_hostname: "{{ esxi_hostname }}"
    name: "{{ vm_name }}"
    template: no
    path: "[datastore1] vm/vm.vmx"
    state: present
```